# Detect for how long a value is set to 0 with a PIR sensor using Javascript

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

I am using a PIR sensor to detect motion within my environment. When there is motion the PIR sensor sends a value of 1 to the console. As soon as it detects no motion it goes to 0 numerous times via a setInterval() every second. Now at that point in time I want to detect how long 0 has been 0 and then at 10 minutes do something. I was thinking of doing a `new Date().getMinutes();` once at start of motion and then another one when motion stopped and comparing those two. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a `var i = 0;` outside of the setInterval() and within the `if (myDigitalValue === 0)` loop I kept `i++` until it hit the amount of seconds I was looking for and when it equaled that I ran a method.

Answer (score 0):

`(new Date()).getMinutes()` will return the "minutes" part of the current time, i.e. where the minute hand would be pointing on a clock.  What you probably want is the absolute time that has passed since a particular point.  Fortunately there's an easy way to determine time difference with the a Date object (or two of them):

```
begin = new Date();
. . . time passes . . .
end = new Date();
timeDiffInMilliseconds = end - begin;
```

In other words, when you subtract one `Date` object from another, you get the time difference in milliseconds (hooray for polymorphic operators).

One advantage this would have is that if you wanted to change the frequency of your test or the length of time, you would just change the relevant one.  With the loop as you describe, the two are tied together unnecessarily, which can be more error prone.